# How to merge two json arrays by property id (SQL Server)

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server, join

I have two columns of json that I would like to join on id into a single select.

**Sample Data**

```
| a                                              | b                                   |
+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| [{id: 1, name: "Alice"},{id:2, name: "Bob"}]   | [{id: 1, age: 30}, {id:2, age: 32}] |
| [{id: 5, name: "Charlie"},{id:6, name: "Dale"} | [{id: 5, age: 20}, {id:6, age: 14}] |
```

**Desired Output**

```
| c                                                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| [{id: 1, name: "Alice", age: 30},{id:2, name: "Bob", age: 32}]    |
| [{id: 5, name: "Charlie", age: 20},{id:6, name: "Dale", age: 14}] |
```

I'd like to do something like

```
select 
id,
name,
age
from openJson(select a from someDb) sd
with (
  id int '$.id',
  age int '$.age'  
)
inner join (
  select 
  id,
  age
  from openJson(select b from someDb)
  with (
    id int  '$.id',
    age int '$.name'
  )
) x
on x.id = sd.id
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that current versions of SQL Server support a `MERGE` function. The only option is `JSON_MODIFY()` function, that can either update the value of an existing property, insert a new `key:value` pair or delete a key.

But in your case, the more appropriate approach is to parse the stored JSON as tables using `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema, join the tables and rebuild the required JSON output again:

```
SELECT 
   c = (
      SELECT a.id, a.name, b.age 
      FROM OPENJSON(v.a) WITH (
         id int '$.id',
         name varchar(50) '$.name'
      ) a
      FULL JOIN OPENJSON(v.b) WITH (
         id int '$.id',
         age int '$.age'
      ) b ON a.id = b.id
      FOR JSON PATH
   )
FROM (VALUES
   ('[{"id": 1, "name": "Alice"}, {"id":2, "name": "Bob"}]',   '[{"id": 1, "age": 30}, {"id":2, "age": 32}]'),
   ('[{"id": 5, "name": "Charlie"}, {"id":6, "name": "Dale"}]', '[{"id": 5, "age": 20}, {"id":6, "age": 14}]')
) v (a, b)
```

Result:

```
c
--------------------------------------------------------------------
[{"id":1,"name":"Alice","age":30},{"id":2,"name":"Bob","age":32}]
[{"id":5,"name":"Charlie","age":20},{"id":6,"name":"Dale","age":14}]
```